# The way that SSAS communicates with SQL Server

Tags: ssas

I have multidimensional cube in SSAS and big SQL server underlying table(more than 100GB) on the same machine. I have just found performance counters of SSAS in Performance monitor and I see number of rows per second that SSAS is reading from SQL server.

But what I don't understand is how are those rows sent from SQL server to SSAS, because when I take a look at the Network tab of the Resource Monitor, I just do not see that amount  of data that has been transferred. sqlservr.exe is not sending that amount of data that I would expect to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe SSAS is going to use the Shared Memory transport protocol since SQL is on the same server as SSAS. Thus it wouldn’t use the NIC or network bandwidth I believe.

You can run the following on the SQL Server during cube processing to double check the net_transport column is shared memory.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

Comment: Thanks, you were right - after I run the query I saw "Shared memory" in the column.